# How can I eliminate this large grass organically?

Tags: grass, weed-control, organic

The pictured grass is growing in a paddy field which has been abandoned for several years. The leaf is in the background and the seed head in the foreground. A fully grown plant can be sized up to nearly 10 feet (3.3 m). It grows as a bush.

We've tried controlling it by burning when we've had no rain for a few weeks in a row, but after the next rain new plants grow. We've also tried to remove the whole plant with its roots, but again it regrows from seeds from somewhere else.

We don't want to use synthetic weedkillers because we want to use the paddy field for growing crops, so how can we eliminate them organically?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Weed eater, scythe, swing blade, pull it up, plow it under, cultivate or harrow it a couple times , power hedge trimmer( hold it close to the ground). But easier to put black plastic sheet over it for several days if it gets any sun.